# Healing power of matzah (Zohar)

Tags: passover, commentaries, matzah, segulah

The [Zohar HaKadosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.183b.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) (thanks to HaLeiVi for pointing this Zohar out) writes that matzah is called "healing food":

> Rather, it can be likened to a King who had a single son who grew weak. One day he had a desire to eat. They said "let the King's son eat this healing food, and until he eats it, let no other kinds of food and nourishment be found throughout the house." And thus they did. After [the son] ate this healing food, [the King] said, "from this point and onward he can eat whatever he desires and it will not be able to harm him."

The Zohar describes it somewhat as "spiritual healing food", rather than physical healing food. However, please see the story of the Rebbe below:

The Lubavitcher Rebbe shares a story of a sick person visiting the Alter Rebbe. The Alter Rebbe then heals the sick person by giving him a small piece of matzah, and a glass of water (see: [Igros Kodesh, vol. 4, p. 352](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15951&st=&pgnum=377&hilite=)).

Also, the [Tiferes Shlomo](https://www.sefaria.org/Tiferet_Shlomo%2C_on_Festivals%2C_Shabbat_HaGadol.11?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Tiferet_Shlomo,_Warsaw,_1867&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) talks about this.

**Question:** *Why does the Zohar states that matzah has spiritual healing powers? Are there any commentaries on the Zohar, or elsewhere where this concept is explained?*

Comment: Are you sure it means a remedy for physical matters? The Zohar quoted by @HaLeiVi implies it is a remedy for spiritual matters.

Comment: @N.T. see the story of the Rebbe I included in the question. It seems that the Zohar is talking about spiritual healing, but there are cases of physical healing. Hence the question.

Comment: Stories of Rebbes operate differently than the rest of Torah. You'd have to ask a Rebbe.

Comment: @N.T. what do you mean with that?

Comment: They do a lot of miracles, with usually no explanation besides their holiness and closeness to G-d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea originates in the [Zohar Hakadosh 2.183](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.2.183b.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

> כַּךָ כַּד נָפְקוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל מִמִּצְרַיִם, לָא הֲוֵי יַדְעֵי עִקָרָא וְרָזָא דִּמְהֵימְנוּתָא, אָמַר קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, יִטְעֲמוּן יִשְׂרָאֵל אַסְוָותָא, וְעַד דְּיֵיכְלוּן אַסְוָותָא דָּא, לָא אִתְחָזֵי לְהוֹן מֵיכְלָא אַחֲרָא. כֵּיוָן דְּאָכְלוּ מַצָּה, דְּאִיהִי אַסְוָותָא לְמֵיעַל וּלְמִנְדַּע בְּרָזָא דִּמְהֵימְנוּתָא. אָמַר קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, מִכָּאן וּלְהָלְאָה אִתְחָזֵי לוֹן חָמֵץ, וְיֵיכְלוּן לֵיהּ, דְּהָא לָא יָכִיל לְנַזְקָא לוֹן. וְכָּל שֶׁכֵּן דִּבְיוֹמָא דְּשָׁבוּעוֹת, אִזְדָּמַן נַהֲמָא עִלָּאָה, דְּאִיהוּ אַסְוָותָא בְּכֹלָּא.

It is being used in reference to the parable mentioned right above. Nevertheless, it is indeed describing the Matzah as a facility to elevate the person to be able to accept Emunah.

The [Maharal in Gevuros Hashem 51](https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.51.9?vhe=Gevurot_Hashem,_with_footnotes_and_annotations_by_Rabbi_Yehoshua_D._Hartman,_Machon_Yerushalyim,_2015-2020&lang=he) describes how the Matzah is a simple—and therefore unearthly—food. He explains how this relates to be of a higher stance and how this was significant in becoming worthy of being removed from Egypt.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for effort. However, I am really interested in why the Zohar states "let Israel taste this healing food"- why is matzah considered a healing bread? And why was it that through this food, B'nei Yisrael became worthy of being removed from Mitzrayim as the Maharal explains.

Comment: In Lehman's story books it says that people kept part of the afikomen on them. And once the daughter of the king was ill and a Jewish person cured her with this. I think in the story of the shach's daughter.

Comment: @interested I've indeed read a story that the afikomen was kept apart. I think it's somewhere in Kaf HaChayim.

Comment: @יהושעק I've edited my question!